# insert two different msg.payload in a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I want to do the query below into a function:
insert into table values (msg.payload.1, msg.payload.2);

this function has two input (2 different msg.payload)
so the code that I am trying to write is:

```
var m={
    topic: "insert into info values ('"+msg.payload+"','"+msg.payload+"');"
};
return m;
```

it is adding two rows in the info table.
but  want to add only one row with two different values.

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I suggest you take this line of questions to the Node-red mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red) where you can lay out the whole idea you are working on. It will be much easier for somebody to help you when they can see the whole picture

Comment: ok thanks, I am working there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood properly you have 2 different nodes feeding data into this function and you want to use the values from these separate messages to build your insert statement.

This is not how Node-RED works, each message is handled totally separately from each other (hence why you see 2 rows added to the DB).

If you want to combine 2 separate messages you will need to make use of the [context](http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/context) to keep state. You will also need a way to identify which message is which when it comes in, this is normally done by message topic, but it could be any unique feature.

Comment: I tried this code: 

if(msg.topic=="cpu")
{
    var m=msg.payload;
}
if (msg.topic=="flahsSize")
{
    var n=msg.payload;
}
var o={
    topic: "insert into info values ('"+m+"','"+n+"');"
};
return o;

but it didnt work; I am confused with the places of the if conditions

Comment: The variables (`m` & `n`) only exist for the length of time it takes to process the individual message. Look at the link to using the context to store state between messages